# flux: how to update a store from within a store

Tags: reactjs, flux

My use case is straightforward. I want to add a notification message to my NotificationStore to display an informational banner to the user in the event that my primary store has been successfully updated.

The simplest way to achieve this appears to be raising an action from within my primary store:

```
   onSaveRule: function() {
        localStorage.setItem("rule", JSON.stringify(_state));
        action.fire("rule successfully saved!"); //mutates NotificationStore
    },
```

However, the *action.fire* line throws the following run-time exception:

**Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.**

Clearly, calling an action from within a store is an anti-pattern.  So what is the correct way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Are you having further issues moving on? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as **accepted**. This helps other people to find what they are looking for. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `storeA` and `storeB` as an example, where your original idea is to have `storeA` firing an `action` and have `storeB` listening to the same `action`.

Instead of directly firing an `action` within `storeA`, you should have `storeB` directly listening to `storeA` state change `triggers`. Meaning upon `storeA` state changes and calls `trigger` to notify your `components`, `storeB` will also be notified by the same `trigger`. `storeB` can then call `getters` to retrieve new states from `storeA`.

In this pattern, `storeB` is a **derived store** of `storeA`. This preserves the *unidirectional data flow* philosophy of the *flux* pattern.